# Python GDAL/OGR, SetAttributeFilter not working

Tags: python, ogr

I'm following the book 'Geoprocessing with python', and I'm just trying to filter countries by their continent with this code:

```
from osgeo import ogr
import ospybook as pb
fn = os.path.join(data_dir, 'ne_10m_admin_0_countries')
ds = ogr.Open(fn)
lyr = ds.GetLayer('ne_10m_admin_0_countries')
lyr.SetAttributeFilter('CONTINENT = "Asia"')
```

I can open and read the file with all the attributes, but when I try to use the **SetAttributeFilter** with Asia for example , I always get the answer:

> ERROR 1: "Asia" not recognised as an available field.

I've tried this with diffrent shapefiles and always get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I simply swapped the single/double quotes in

`lyr.SetAttributeFilter('CONTINENT = "Asia"')`

So, the correct syntax is

`lyr.SetAttributeFilter("CONTINENT = 'Asia' ")`